# Get return value from Controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

What I want is, I want to check whether there is a file in the database or not. To do this I have a method in the controller which checks this and returns a boolean for the corresponding case. It looks like this:

```
public bool fileInDb(int empId)
    {
        using (SLADbContext db = new SLADbContext())
        {
            bool file = db.CompetenceUploads.Any(x => x.EmployeeId == empId);
            if (file)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I simply just check if there is any file assigned to the given employee.

Now I would like to call this method from my javascript in the view, and get the return value, so that I can let the user know, if there is a file assigned to the selected employee or not. It may look like this:

```
$("#get-file").click(function() {

        empId: $("#EmployeeSelect").val();
        var fileInDb = // Get the return value from the method 'fileInDb'

        if(fileInDb) {
            // Let the user download the file he/she requested
            var url = "@Url.Action("GetUploadedFile", "Competence")";
            this.href = url + '?empId=' + encodeURIComponent($("#EmployeeSelect").val());
        } else {
            alert("There is no file assigned to this employee.");
        }
    });
```

So my question now is, how do I get the get the return value from the method in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest few changes here:

Change your `controller` method to have `return` type `ActionResult` or `JsonResult` and I prefer `JsonResult` would be enough here and retrun `Json` response from `controller` and manipulate this method with **[`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**. You also need to change parameter to `string` because the `parameter` will be received as `Json string`.

```
public JsonResult fileInDb(string eId) //change signature to string and then convert to int 
{
    int empId=Convert.ToInt32(eId);
    using (SLADbContext db = new SLADbContext())
    {
         bool file = db.CompetenceUploads.Any(x => x.EmployeeId == empId);
         if (file)
         {
             return Json(new { result = true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
         else
         {
             return Json(new { result = false},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
    }
}
```

Now your `ajax-get` call would be as below:

```
$("#get-file").click(function() {
   var eId= $("#EmployeeSelect").val();
   $.get('/YourControllerName/fileInDb',{'eId':eId},function(response){
       //you just need to get the response so $.get is enough to manipulate
       //this will be called once you get the response from controller, typically a callback
       if(response.result) //same result variable we are returning from controller.
       {
            // Let the user download the file he/she requested
            var url = "@Url.Action("GetUploadedFile", "Competence")";
            this.href = url + '?empId=' + encodeURIComponent($("#EmployeeSelect").val());
       } else {
            alert("There is no file assigned to this employee.");
       }
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seems like a good solution. However, I am confused about the 'response'-parameter - what is it, and is it the "real" parameter or is it to be substituted with somehting? :)

Comment: Nope.. Keep it as it is.. Its just a reference to server response.. :) You can give name of your own.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set-up a single page script using your ASP `fileInDb` function and then communicate with that page using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) from the browser. If you're unfamiliar with AJAX I'd recommend using the [jQuery implementation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibjs-rvqvJAhUDcw8KHRQ0AXUQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.ajax%2F&usg=AFQjCNET1WrVqP-BPFBEQY1R7V6crOtd1w&sig2=TKw8nU9GkqK0hIb-Uo0GHQ&bvm=bv.108194040,d.ZWU) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend create a method to call, returning a JsonResult

```
    public JsonResult fileInDb(int empId)
    {
         // your code - set fileExists to true/false

        JsonResult returnObj = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                FileExists = fileExists ;
            }
        };

        return Json(returnObj);
    }
```

in your javascript code use $.ajax

```
       $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("fileInDb")',
            data: { 'empId': someVar },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                  if (response.Data.FileExists === true) {
                    // do something
                  }   else {
                   // it was false
                  }
                },
            error: function (er) {
                alert('Error!' + er);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and ajax to achieve this. Call your method using an ajax call from your client code. Here is an example as a reference :[Calling controller method from view](http://www.codecompiled.com/using-jquery-get-and-post-ajax-methods-in-mvc/)